# Rectangle's not positioning/working correctly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying make a simple game with Libgdx in Android Studio, which a player moves a spaceship left / right, dodging asteroids coming down the screen randomly. Everything is working fine except the Rectangles are either not positioning correctly on the asteroids, or are not registering overlap to end the game after collision.

Currently there is only collision ending the game if the player is sat against the right hand side of the game when an asteroid comes down, any other location (even near the right hand edge) does nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a class for the Ship:

```
    package com.mygdx.game.Sprites;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
    import com.mygdx.game.Game2;



    public class Ship {
    private static int gravity;
    private static int MOVEMENT = 50;


    private Vector3 position;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private Rectangle bounds;

    private Texture ship;

    public Ship(int x, int y){
        position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        ship = new Texture("Ship3.png");
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, ship.getWidth(), ship.getHeight());
        // - 10 maybe for shape not being square
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        velocity.add(gravity, 0, 0);
        velocity.scl(dt);
        position.add(velocity.x, MOVEMENT*dt, 0);

        if (position.x < 0)
            position.x = 0;

        if(position.x + ship.getWidth() >= Game2.WIDTH/2) {
        position.x = Game2.WIDTH/2 - ship.getWidth();

       bounds.setPosition(position.x, position.y);

        }


    }
    public Vector3 getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public Texture getTexture() {
        return ship;
    }

    public void turnLeft(){
        gravity = -100;

    }

    public void turnRight() {
        gravity = 100;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds(){
        return bounds;
    }

    public boolean collides(Rectangle asta){
        return asta.overlaps(bounds);
    }
}
```

A `class for Asta (Asteroid) :

```
> package com.mygdx.game.Sprites;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.particles.influencers.ColorInfluencer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

import java.util.Random;



public class Asta {
public static final int ASTA_HEIGHT = 36;
private static final int FLUCTUATION = 150;
private static final int ASTA_GAP = 80;

private Texture leftasta, rightasta;
private Vector2 posLeftAsta, posRightAsta;
private Rectangle boundsRight, boundsLeft;

private Random rand;

public Asta(float y) {
    leftasta = new Texture("Rock.png");
    rightasta = new Texture("Rock.png");
    rand = new Random();

    posRightAsta = new Vector2( rand.nextInt(FLUCTUATION) + ASTA_GAP, y);
    posLeftAsta = new Vector2( posRightAsta.x - ASTA_GAP - 
    rightasta.getWidth(), y);

    boundsRight = new Rectangle(posRightAsta.x, posRightAsta.y, 
    rightasta.getWidth(), rightasta.getHeight());
    boundsLeft = new Rectangle(posLeftAsta.x, posLeftAsta.y, 
    leftasta.getWidth(), leftasta.getHeight());


 }

    public Texture getLeftasta() {
        return leftasta;
    }

    public Texture getRightasta() {
        return rightasta;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosLeftAsta() {
        return posLeftAsta;
    }

    public Vector2 getPosRightAsta() {
        return posRightAsta;
    }

    public void reposition(float y){
        posRightAsta.set( rand.nextInt(FLUCTUATION) + ASTA_GAP, y);
        posLeftAsta.set( posRightAsta.x - ASTA_GAP - rightasta.getWidth(), y);

        boundsRight.setPosition(posRightAsta.x, y);
        boundsLeft.setPosition(posLeftAsta.x, y);



    }

    public boolean collides(Rectangle player){
        return player.overlaps(boundsRight) || player.overlaps(boundsLeft);
    }

    }
```

and my PlayState:

```
    package com.mygdx.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.mygdx.game.Game2;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Asta;
import com.mygdx.game.Sprites.Ship;


public class PlayState extends State {
    private static final int ASTA_SPACING = 125;
    private static final int ASTA_COUNT = 4;

    private Ship ship;
    private Texture background;
    private Array<Asta> astas;


    public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
       ship = new Ship(Game2.WIDTH/4, Game2.HEIGHT/8);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Game2.WIDTH/2, Game2.HEIGHT/2);
        // /2
        background = new Texture("Background1.png");
        astas = new Array<Asta>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= ASTA_COUNT; i++){
            astas.add(new Asta(i * ASTA_SPACING + Asta.ASTA_HEIGHT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
        ship.turnLeft();
        {
            if (Gdx.input.getX() > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2)
            {
                ship.turnRight();
            }
            else
            {
                ship.turnLeft();
            }
        }
        }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        handleInput();
        ship.update(dt);

        cam.position .y = ship.getPosition().y+50 ;
        //moves the camera focus around the ship;

        for (Asta asta: astas){
            if (cam.position.y - (cam.viewportHeight/2) > asta.getPosRightAsta().y + asta.getRightasta().getHeight()){
                asta.reposition(asta.getPosRightAsta().y + ((Asta.ASTA_HEIGHT + ASTA_SPACING) * ASTA_COUNT));
            }
            if (asta.collides(ship.getBounds()))
                gsm.set(new MenuState(gsm));
        }

        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(background, 0, cam.position.y - (cam.viewportHeight / 2), Game2.WIDTH /2, Game2.HEIGHT /2);
        ///2
        sb.draw(ship.getTexture(), ship.getPosition().x, ship.getPosition().y);
        for (Asta asta : astas) {
            sb.draw(asta.getRightasta(), asta.getPosRightAsta().x, asta.getPosRightAsta().y);
            sb.draw(asta.getLeftasta(), asta.getPosLeftAsta().x, asta.getPosRightAsta().y);}
            sb.end();
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose () {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your `Asteroids` are static, If no where is code for their movement ?

Comment: Sorry I must of explained it strangely, The Asteroids stay still/are static, while the Ship moves up the screen, then once the Asteroids go below the screen they are re positioned to the top,                                                                                   "public void reposition(float y)" does this